# Is there such a Hasse diagram satisfying these properties?

Tags: graph-theory

[I'm learning about the Sperner property and found the following question really mind blowing

[image]

By now I've come up with a case:

Removing the maximal node of a hasse diagram for the Boolean algebra $B_k$. Then it must be graded since every maximal chain of the remaining diagram has the same length. And it doesn't satisfy the Sperner property since the number of elements in its antichain is greater than its level. It's easy to see that it's not rank-symmetric as well. But I'm not sure if it's rank-unimodal.

Comment: Please include the text of the problem instead of just an image. It sounds like you may have misunderstood the Sperner property. And are you missing the definition of rank-unimodal?